# Remove or identify Photoshop on Open With List

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, adobe-photoshop

### Problem

When using Windows Explorer's `Open With...` context menu, many image types show two Photoshop CS5 entries. One is the 32-bit version, the other is the 64-bit version. However, they both use the exact same icon and text, so it's impossible to tell them apart without actually launching one.

Is there a way to remove one or the other from this list, or possibly alter the text to identify the bitness? I use Photoshop x64 almost exclusively, barring the few occasions I work with the [BetterJPEG plugin](http://www.betterjpeg.com/jpeg-plug-in.htm), which only comes in 32-bit.

### What I've Tried

- I have tried [OpenWithView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/open_with_view.html) but to no avail. It doesn't even show the Photoshop options. I suspect a WOW64 redirection issue, as the app itself is 32-bit.
- I manually visited the Registry as per [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258860), but again, no joy. Photoshop doesn't use those particular keys. (Illustrator does though!)

### Additional Info

It seems the Photoshop option(s) are not coming from the `OpenWithList` subkey, but rather the [`OpenWithProgID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166549(v=vs.80).aspx) key. However, removing/deleting the key(s) has no effect, as they are recreated the next time that filetype is right-clicked.

Suggestions?